# Custom <form> element with URI Template support

Tags: html, web-component, custom-element, uritemplate

Is there a [custom element](https://customelements.io), which allow the use of [RFC6570 URI templates](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6570)? This is very similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15352739/how-to-submit-form-with-get-method-and-using-uri-template). Here's the sample HTML used there.

```
<form action="/orders/{id}" method="get">
   <input type="text" name="id"/>
   <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>
```

I'm asking specifically about a Web Component though, so something like either

```
<form is="templated-form">
```

or

```
<templated-form>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's very simple to create if it doesn't exist yet.

Just register a `<template-form>` custom element inheriting from `HTMLFormElement.prototype`, and extending the `form` element, that will make use of your favorite *RFC6570 URI templates* compliant JavaScript library.

For example, this one : https://medialize.github.io/URI.js/uri-template.html, or those ones : https://github.com/medialize/URI.js/#uri-template.

You'll have to use the *extended* notation in order to take advantage of the semantics of the `<form>` element :

```
<form is="template-form">
```

Comment: Yes, well thank you, but it's not what I was asking :)